# Extension installation fail in Bolt CMS 2.2.8

Tags: bolt-cms

I`m trying to install an extension through standard Extras / View Install Extensions and there is problem:

Composer Error:

> RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/home/k/kurkinst/untwist/public_html/extensions/vendor/bolt/boltforms)
>   [recursivedirectoryiterator.--constructthis link]: failed to open dir:
>   No such file or directory %ERROR_LOCATION%

All folders are 777 rights ... What can it be?
Site is at the webserver, there is no problem with installation on the local server.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, having seen this happen, that the web host is using symlinks.